# how does the os know which hdd it booted from?

Tags: operating-system

In a computer having two or more hdds(Hard disk drive, such as hard disks, cd-roms, usb disks), the bootloader uses bios int 13h/42h to load sectors from the booted hdd. When the os is loaded, I guess it will erase all the bios code and scan all the hdds available by itself. Before that, I think the os must know which hdd it booted from. The only way the os can know that is to ask bios, I think. For example, there are 3 usb disks, 3 hard disks(on the pci bus) attatched to the computer, the os must know which one it booted from. So I want to ask how the os gets that infomation?

Comment: Might find some useful information, eg: https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/telux/lin-club_files/linux-boot/slide0002.htm , https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Category:Boot_loaders

Comment: See also chapters "boot sequence" and "bootloader" on https://wiki.osdev.org